# How to return 2factor code from delegate inside non-ui thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, vk

I've worked only with WinForms and decided to go on WPF
but I've met a problem which I can't resolve:

I want to authorize on vk.com through vkApi, and to do that, I have to pass delegate returning *string* with code for 2factor auth

```
p.TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
                {                 
                        var two = new TwoFactor();
                        two.ShowDialog();
                        return two.Data;
                };
```

I decided^ to make a dialog-window but got "**The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this**"

```
vk.Authorize(p);
```

Okay, so it means that this^ method creates a new thread inside and I need to show my dialog from UI thread, am i right?

I found that Dispatcher.Invoke could help me (not BeginInvoke, cuz i need to return *string*) and have written this

```
return Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {                    
                            var two = new TwoFactor();
                            two.ShowDialog();
                            return two.Data;
                        }));
```

But now, my app is just freezing and no dialogs appear!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.8), then you'll see that the return of `Invoke()` is `void` which means you can't return anything just with `return myVar`. You should pass the data directly to the model which needs it.

Comment: what about Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult>) ?

Comment: try to use eventhandler: raise event in your function and process it in the main thread

Comment: Do you also have an issue with another modal dialog, e.g. `MessageBox`? With `MessageBox` I can't reproduce your issue. Send more code to see where you do invoke/use your code snippets. Also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I found that api has blocked main thread, so I called AuthorizeAsync() and main thread became avaliable to show dialog by Dispatcher.Invoke()

It looks like this:

```
public void Func()
{
    vkParams.TwoFactor = () =>
    {
        return Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {                    
            var two = new TwoFactor();
            two.ShowDialog();
            return two.Data;
        }));
    }
} 

private async void Auth()
{
    vkParams.Login = t_login.Text;
    vkParams.Password = t_pass.Text;
    await vkApi.AuthorizeAsync(vkParams);
}
```